# JAXB write namespaces to one class from other classes

Tags: java, namespaces, jaxb, jaxb2

When i create a jaxbcontext with all my classes, jaxb build xml for a class with a namespace from other class. 
If i pass to jaxbcontext only one class it work fine.
My classes are generated by xjc.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {

 })
@XmlRootElement(name = "eReq")
public class EReq {
...
```

And when i pass only this class to jaxbcontext the output is following.

```
<eReq><status>UNBLOCKED</status></eReq>
```

But i put all my classes into jaxb context output will be like this:

```
<eReq xmlns:ns2="myns1" xmlns:ns3="myns2" xmlns:ns4="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><status>UNBLOCKED</status></eReq>
```

This is namespaces from my other classes. Why jaxb put it to this class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why jaxb put it to this class?

Because the JAXB context contains the superset of all namespaces that it's created with, and it just puts them all in each document it generates.

It does this because the namespaces need to be added to the root element (to avoid hugely wasteful re-declaration of namespaces on each child element), and it doesn't know in advance which namespaces are required for any given set of bound objects (JAXB supports incremental serialization).

So the JAXB runtime probably *could* avoid doing that; but it doesn't.

If you don't like it, then you need to build multiple contexts.